# How to make an ajax call to a C# file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I would like to create an aspx file with an ajax call in it pointing to a method in the C# file, the latter runs query to a database and returns the data to the aspx file to instantiate a dataTable object in jQuery.

I have already written something in the 2 files but I don't understand how to go on, even on the internet I had difficulty understanding how to do it.

I would need to know which object or variable I should give in response to the ajax call made in the aspx file to instantiate the dataTable object, and I would need to understand why in my specific case I cannot communicate via the ajax call to the GetData function.

Here is what I did:

-JavaScript Code

```js
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sph_table_00.aspx/GetData")%>';
$(function () {
new DataTable('#example', {
    ajax: {
        "type": 'POST',
        "url": pageUrl,
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "dataType": 'json',
        "success": function (msg) {
            alert("Success: " + msg.d);
            
            //EXAMPLE
            let out = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                out.push([i + '-1', i + '-2']);
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
                callback({
                    draw: data.draw,
                    data: out,
                    recordsTotal: 5000000,
                    recordsFiltered: 5000000
                });
            }, 150);
        }
    },
    processing: true,
    ordering: false,
    scroller: true,
    scrollY: 200,
    searching: false,
    serverSide: true
});
}
```

- C# Code

```cs
public partial class Sph_table_00 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetData()
    {
    if (Common.openConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA) != null)
{
    OLEConnectionSPHERA = Common.openConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA);

    string tabella = "";
    string titolo = "";
    string reparto = "";
    string p1 = "";
    string p2 = "";
    string p3 = "";
    string p4 = "";
    string p5 = "";

    Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("TABELLA") != null)
        tabella = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("TABELLA");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("TITOLO") != null)
        titolo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("TITOLO");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("REPARTO") != null)
        reparto = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("REPARTO");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P1") != null)
        p1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P1");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P2") != null)
        p2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P2");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P3") != null)
        p3 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P3");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P4") != null)
        p4 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P4");

    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P5") != null)
        p5 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P5");

    if (tabella == "" && titolo == "")
    {
        Response.Write("Nessun parametro");
        return;
    }

    if (reparto != "")
        Session["REPARTO"] = reparto;
    else if (reparto == "Azienda")
        reparto = "";
    else
        reparto = Session["REPARTO"].ToString();

    string queryMaster = $"select * from WEB_QUERY where tablename = '{tabella}'";

    if (Common.executeQuery(queryMaster, OLEConnectionSPHERA) != null)
        oleDbDataReader_QUERY = Common.executeQuery(queryMaster, OLEConnectionSPHERA);

    while (oleDbDataReader_QUERY.Read())
    {
        string query = oleDbDataReader_QUERY.GetValue(oleDbDataReader_QUERY.GetOrdinal("QUERYSELECT")).ToString().Replace("@PREP", reparto);
        //string query = "SELECT * from s_odl";

        if (Common.executeQuery(query, OLEConnectionSPHERA) != null)
            oleDbDataReader_CDL = Common.executeQuery(query, OLEConnectionSPHERA);

        for (int i = 0; i < oleDbDataReader_CDL.FieldCount; i++)
            ListaNomiColonne.Add(oleDbDataReader_CDL.GetName(i).ToString());

        while (oleDbDataReader_CDL.Read())
        {
            foreach (string field in ListaNomiColonne)
            {
                ListaDati.Add(oleDbDataReader_CDL.GetValue(oleDbDataReader_CDL.GetOrdinal(field)).ToString());
            }
        }
        oleDbDataReader_CDL.Dispose();
        oleDbDataReader_CDL.Close();
    }

    oleDbDataReader_QUERY.Dispose();
    oleDbDataReader_QUERY.Close();

    if (Common.closeConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA) != null)
        OLEConnectionSPHERA = Common.closeConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA);
}
    }
}
```

- HTML

```html
<table id="example" style="width:100%" class="table table-striped display nowrap">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, we don't know what you want to do in that method either... It's called `GetData`, so I guess, query the database and get data? I'd start with some tutorials on how to do that in C#.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the code inside the GetData() method to make the query to the DB I have and it works. But I don't know what value I have to return to the "success" of the ajax call in order to create the datatable.

Comment: [Edit] your question to make it clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @Loryxz2000 - start with returning the DB data as JSON. the properties of the JSON object should match your datatable you defined in your javascript. your GetData() signature should be `public static string GetData()`.

Comment: @thewallrus - Thanks for the help, I added static to the method but still have problems with the communication between the 2 files. The error of the ajax call is: DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/7. From DevTools of Chrome I see this error in console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it not at all clear what/how/why/where this comes from:

```
 if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P4") != null)
    p4 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("P4");
```

I mean, the WHOLE idea of a web method call (ajax) is that you don't have to post up a whole web page. Of course then calling JUST a web method means that this end point will have to be passed ANY  data it requires. And you don't have to use ParseQuery, or even have to parse out the values (this is all done for you automatic).

So, let's make a really simple web method call. We will have 3 text boxes on the web page with First, middle and Last Name.

We then will have a 3rd text box for the resulting full name. The web method call will be passed the 3 values, and return a string of the full name to be placed in the full name text box.

Note how web methods EXPECT a set of defined parameters. Web methods have zero clue about controls on the current web page.
So, context of web methods are static in that they don't have knowledge of the controls on the current web page.

And the same goes for the use of parameters that you pass. You look to be using P1 to P4, but I see no such value(s) having been passed in your web method call (nor are even the values defined in your sample code).

Values (parameters) passed to web methods cannot be some guess. So you explicit define, setup and pass such values.

This is thus much like calling a c# routine from the client side JavaScript code. Hence parameters and values passed must be setup correctly and MUST match the c# function parameters (the so called function signature).

So, then this markup and jQuery code:

```
        <div style="width:30%">

            First Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" 
                CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" >  
            </asp:TextBox>

            Middle Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddle" runat="server" 
                CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" >  
            </asp:TextBox>

            Last Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" 
                CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" >  
            </asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdCombine" runat="server" Text="Combine into Fullname"
                CssClass="btn myshadow"
                OnClientClick="GetFullName();return false;"
                />
            <br />
            <br />
            Full Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFull" runat="server" 
                CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" >  
            </asp:TextBox>


            <script>

                function GetFullName () {

                    var sFirst = $('#txtFirst').val()
                    var sMid = $('#txtMiddle').val()
                    var sLast = $('#txtLast').val()

                    var myParms = JSON.stringify({
                        FirstName: sFirst,
                        LastName: sLast,
                        MiddleName: sMid
                    })

                    var sURL = "AjaxTest1.aspx/FullName"
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: sURL,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: myParms,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (Data) {
                            $('#txtFull').val(Data.d)
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                            alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                        }
                    });

                }

            </script>
        </div>
```

and the code beind (web method)

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string FullName(  string FirstName,
                                    string LastName,
                                    string MiddleName)
    {
        string sResult = "";
        sResult = $"{FirstName} {MiddleName} {LastName}";
        return sResult ;
    }
```

Note VERY close in above, the parameters from the client side JavaScript match the EXACT names of the parameters defined in the above c# function.

Note that the order does not matter but only that the parameters exist, and match the defines ones in the web method.

Of course some of the JavaScript code could have been reduced, but I spread out a few extra lines of code to make clear how this works.

Running above results in this:

[image]